# Can I extend classes overwriting base class properties in ES6?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm looking to do something like the following, purely with ES6/JS:

```
class ParentClass {
    prop = true;
    constructor() {
        console.log("Prop is", this.prop);
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    prop = false;
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

const childClassInstance = new ChildClass();

//
```

`"Prop is false"`

Is this possible with ES6? Everything I've read/tried points at the context of the base constructor being what it was initialised with.

Comment: ES6 does not have class properties. Class properties are a [Stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) and not yet part of any ECMAScript spec.

Answer (score 0):

You could check in parent class if prop param is passed or not and use that value or default `true` value.

```js
class ParentClass {
  constructor(prop) {
    this.prop = prop != undefined ? prop : true;
    console.log("Prop is", this.prop);
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  constructor(...props) {
    super(...props);
  }
}

const one = new ChildClass(false);
const two = new ChildClass();
```